# Why I can't input float numbers to t?

Tags: python, numpy, range

I have to code the basic logistic growth which later will be used for tumor growth.

I have to put float values to t but it gives me an error and I think it is because the range can take only integers. But the range must be t. Is there any way to do this?

Logistic Growth

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

val = float(input("Enter your value: ")) 
r = .25 # growth rate / year ,|(birth/death rate)
K = 100 # carrying capacity
t=val
num = np.zeros(t+1)
num[0] = 1

for i in range(t):
    num[i+1] = num[i]+r*num[i]*(1-num[i]/K)
    row= (i+1,'\t\t',format(num[i], '.8f'))
    print (row)

    with open('plot.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=' ')
            writer.writerow(row)
            csvFile.close()

plt.plot(range(t+1),num, 'b')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel(' Cell Number')
plt.title('Logistic Growth')
plt.axvline(np.argmax(np.diff(num)),  color = 'k'  )

plt.show()
```

Comment: How can a range be till a floating number? You do know that floating numbers are not really precise and are dependent on machine implementation

Comment: Hi @Z.Boz - Please mark the most helpful answer by clicking the check mark next to it. If your question is not answered, please comment to clarify. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with whole numbers stored in a `float`, you could just convert `t` to `int`:

```
>>> range(int(7.0))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you do need floating-point ranges, [`np.arange()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) works for that:

```
>>> np.arange(0.2, 6.4, 0.5)
array([ 0.2,  0.7,  1.2,  1.7,  2.2,  2.7,  3.2,  3.7,  4.2,  4.7,  5.2,
        5.7,  6.2])
```